# ngCordova Google analytics ($cordovaGoogleAnalytics)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, plugins, google-analytics, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the 'https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git' plugin with ngCordova. I have added the plugin and added ngCordova as a dependency in my controller.

when I try to set:

```
$cordovaGoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
```

I get this error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'startTrackerWithId' of undefined'.

I have set my analytics up as a mobile app in the Google dashboard.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Where $cordovaGoogleAnalytics is declared? Is it a param of the controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens because you are trying to use analytics plugin before it's initialized by cordova.

Just wrap the initialization recursevely with a setTimetout:

```
function _waitForAnalytics(){
    if(typeof analytics !== 'undefined'){
        $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.debugMode();
        $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
        $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.trackView('APP first screen');
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            _waitForAnalytics();
        },250);
    }
};
_waitForAnalytics();
```

Comment: Accepting the above answer, but needed to add '_waitForAnalytics();' after the last line of code above. Thank you for the response :-)

Comment: The option above works fine, but I also tried with the method here (http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ngcordova-google-analytics-cordovagoogleanalytics/12619/3) and it also works. one method uses ngcordova and one does not.

Comment: They are different events, just because device is ready is fired, doesn't mean that Google analytics has been Initialized already

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the best way of tracking with google analytics

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    if(typeof analytics !== undefined) {
      analytics.debugMode();
      analytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-xxxxxxxx-x");
      analytics.trackView($state.current.name);
    } else {
      console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
    }
  });
});
```

This will track on each state change on the application and will give you the state that user is on.